# Quota on time-based gscript tiggers

Tags: google-apps-script

I have got a script that I need to run periodically (preferably once every half hour). I have made an hourly trigger, but I'm not sure of the limitations on how many times this can be run in a day without hitting the quota for my standard Gmail account.

I have found the ["Quotas for Google Services" page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), however, I'm not sure what category it falls under and therefore how many triggers I can have daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the use of triggers, from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

| Feature | Consumer (e.g., gmail.com) and G Suite free edition (legacy) | Google Workspace accounts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Triggers total runtime | 90 min / day | 6 hr / day |

Please bear in mind that other quotas might apply too.